# Create a loop for web scraping with selenium in python

Tags: python, html, loops, selenium, web-scraping

I want to create a loop so that I can scrape the individual time figures for each horse on all eight races from the at the races website.

Below is an example of the first race (17:15) of eight:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/6-October-2018/1715'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="racecard-tabs 1061960"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))
```

The next race (17:45) would have the following url:

```
url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/6-October-2018/1745'
```

And the id in the following code keeps changing with the url

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="racecard-tabs 1061961"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

So for the 17:15, the racecard-tabs becomes  1061960

for the  17:45, the racecard-tabs becomes 1061961

the 18:15, raecard-tabs becomes 1061963, and so on.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. You can even change the date and the rest will be automatically be executed for you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def races(main_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(main_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    races = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('time-location')
    races = [race.text[:5] for race in races]
    races = [race.replace(':', '') for race in races]

    driver.close()

    return races

def scrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('racecard-ajax-link')[1].click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))

    for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
        horseName = horse.find_element_by_class_name('form-link').text
        times = horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time')
        times = [time.text for time in times]
        print('{}: {}'.format(horseName, times))
    print()

    driver.close()

def main():
    date = '6-October-2018'
    main_url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/' + date
    for race in races(main_url):
        url = main_url + '/' + race
        print(url)
        scrape(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks again for your work! although part of the code keeps throwing up an error: races = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('time-location')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    races = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('time-location')
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: Yes I get SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement. If I try and run the code after the imports, i.e. from def races(main_url): I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax and it highlights 'def' at the 'scrape(url): line of code.

Comment: The code is really fine. Make a new python file and copy my EXACT code and run it. You're doing something wrong

Comment: Why would you have: from def race(main_url)? I never wrote it like that

Comment: No, I mean that's where I try and run the code 'from' after the imports. I don't actually use the word 'from' in the code. I've copied and pasted line for line and still get - SyntaxError: invalid syntax - and it highlights the 'def' for the scrape(url): line of the code

Comment: actually, sorry it's been posted above your ^^ the code copied and pasted exactly as I am pasting it in Python and getting the Syntax error.

Comment: They are not the same. Notice the tabs on the lines. Make them EXACTLY the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764380/loop-not-working-as-its-throwing-up-a-syntax-error?noredirect=1#comment92451714_52764380 - took a screenshot as SO won't let me reproduce your code without adding indnents that are not part of your original code.

Comment: @BrianC I suspect something is going on in the copying process from this answer to your own terminal; tabs and spaces might be interchanged somewhere. Do check whether tabs and spaces are the same after you copied them as they are in this answer.

Comment: Don't copy huge blocks of code like that into an interactive shell, these won't usually work. Save it to a .py file and execute that.

Comment: Shout out to everyone who helped with this, but especially jxpython, who put the code together. As Andras Deak suggested I was just copying and pasting huge blocks of code before saving to .py executable file. This has now resolved the issue!! Cheers, all!!